# Pyspark, when Column value starts with x, write as y

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hi folks I'm augmenting my DF was wondering if you can give a helping hand.

```
df = df.withColumn(('COUNTRY'), when(col("COUNTRY").startsWith("US"), "US").otherwise("null"))
```

What I am trying to achieve is resetting the column to, where a column value starts with US, such as `US_Rules_Forever` - to rewrite the dataframe simply as just `US`. Other variables to be set with `null`

```
ID     COUNTRY
1      US_RULES
2      US_SANDWICH
3      USA_CLICKING
4      GLOBAL_CHICKEN_SANDWICH

ID     COUNTRY
1      US
2      US
3      US
4      null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.startswith), it should be `startswith`, not `startsWith`. `w` should not be capitalized.

```
df2 = df.withColumn('COUNTRY', when(col("COUNTRY").startswith("US"), "US"))

df2.show()
+---+-------+
| ID|COUNTRY|
+---+-------+
|  1|     US|
|  2|     US|
|  3|     US|
|  4|   null|
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

mck was right - it was a syntax issue. Posting this for fellow devs:

```
df = df.withColumn(('COUNTRY'), when(col("COUNTRY").startswith("US"), "US").otherwise("null"))
```